# Импорт .sql файла в sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql

Сталкнулся с такой проблемой, нужно импортировать `db.sql` в `sql server` в `database`. Работал с mySql-ом там в phpmyadmin-e просто нажимайш кнопку "импорт" выбираешь файл вот и все, а здесь куча кнопок не смог разобраться. Кто знает, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте консольную команду SQLCMD.

Comment: Получилось отличная вещь..

Comment: Вот и хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на файл. Возможно это просто создание таблиц и bulk insert, так что его можно просто выполнить.

Comment: 90.000 строк =)

Comment: Самое интересное в начале. Там же может быть комментарий по использованию.